# Convert a [][]string into []byte

Tags: go, slice

Am trying to convert a 2D slice of string into 1d slice of bytes but it is very slow. Any better way to do ?,

```
func TwoDstringsliceToOneByteSlice(csvRecords [][]string) []byte {
    var singleSlice []byte
    for _, record := range csvRecords {
    for _, item := range record {
        singleSlice = append(singleSlice, []byte(item)...)
    }
    }
    return singleSlice
}
```

Comment: What are you comparing this to that leads you the believe it is slow? This is how you would concatenate a number of strings to a slice of bytes.

Comment: so around 17k records take 2 mins to process..hence i was thinking if there is a way we can use goroutines to make it faster?

Comment: Unless the records themselves are huge, 17k records is not much, and the copying is probably not your bottleneck. The benchmark I mentioned below copied over 1GB or records and only took 280ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each `append` in your example first copies its argument — type conversion between a `string` and a `[]byte` (and vice-versa) is one of the few places in Go which do copy the data, — and then quite possibly copies the destination slice to create more room in it for what is being appended.

One obvious approach to improve this is something like

```golang
func TwoDstringsliceToOneByteSlice(csvRecords [][]string) []byte {
  var buf bytes.Buffer
  for _, record := range csvRecords {
    for _, item := range record {
        buf.WriteString(item)
    }
  }
  return buf.Bytes()
}
```

Note that if you intend to use the result for "reading" — as is the case of using such a data as the payload for a HTTP POST request, you can just use the `bytes.Buffer` right away — without getting the byte slice out of it — as `bytes.Buffer` implements `io.Reader`.

The second refinement would be to first calculate the total length of all the strings, then preallocate the target slice.
You could then either call `.Grow()` on the `bytes.Buffer` before writing to it or ditch `bytes.Buffer` and use subslicing and `copy` (but I would advise against this — by now).

…But still, as @JimB correctly points out, unil we know how you're measuring the performance, it's hard to sensibly guess.

Comment: @hss, please start with [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro), then move to [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices).

Comment: Also, as @hobbs pointed out in their respective answer to your first question which you have deleted, it's possible to implement a reader which just reads from what you call "2D slice" directly, not performing any conversion at all.